Difference between React navigation and react-tv-space-navigation for Apple TV APP
I'm relatively new to React Native and I'm trying to create an Apple TV app with a UI similar to the one shown in the image below.

I'm a bit confused about the navigation libraries to use. From what I've gathered, React Navigation seems suitable for top tabs navigation, which I intend to use for the top tabs. However, for the sliders (or shelves as I call them), I came across react-tv-space-navigation, which seems tailored for TV app navigation.
My question is, am I correct in understanding that for the top tabs I should use React Navigation and for the sliders (shelves) I should use react-tv-space-navigation? Or is there a better approach for achieving this UI?
I'm building this app using React Native-TVOS. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
